# Audit.NET and Asp Net Core Razor Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, audit.net

I am using razor pages in my ASP.NET Core application. I need to enable logging with [Audit.NET library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Audit.NET/), it works fine with ASP.NET MVC controllers, but it doesn't work with Razor pages.

Here is an example how I declare a `PageModel` class with `Audit` attribute:

```cs
[Audit(EventTypeName = "{area}/{Page} ({verb})",
   IncludeResponseBody = true,
   IncludeRequestBody = true,
   IncludeHeaders = true,
   IncludeModel = true)]
public class LoginIndexModel : PageModel
{
  ...
}
```

It throws `NullReferenceException` when `AuditAttribute` action filter is invoked.

Here is the method declared in `AuditAttribute`:
(As I understand `actionDescriptor` parameter cannot be casted to `ControllerActionDescriptor`)

```cs
private bool IsActionIgnored(ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
{
    if (actionDescriptor == null)
        return false;

    return ((IEnumerable<object>)(actionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor).ControllerTypeInfo
               .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuditIgnoreAttribute), true)).Any<object>() || 
           ((IEnumerable<object>)(actionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor).MethodInfo
               .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AuditIgnoreAttribute), true)).Any<object>();
}
```

So what can I do in this case?
Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: This will need some work to make it compatible with Razor Pages, I've created [the following issue](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/329) to track the progress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The audit mechanism for MVC was implemented with an action filter, but action filters are [not supported on Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-3.1#filter-types).

For razor pages, a [Page Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/filter?view=aspnetcore-3.1#implement-razor-page-filters-globally) is provided instead, so you can configure the auditing.

Use the provided `AuditPageFilter` instead of the `[Audit]` attribute.

Basically you just need to add the filter to the collection on your startup logic, for example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages()
        .AddMvcOptions(options =>
        {
            options.Filters.Add(new Audit.Mvc.AuditPageFilter()
            {
                IncludeHeaders = true, ...
            });
        });
}
```

Check the readme [here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/master/src/Audit.Mvc/README.md#razor-pages).